# Unable to infer closure type in the current context in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to pass simple string array in list using ForEach in SwiftUI.

- here is my code

  ```
  import SwiftUI

  struct ContentView : View {
  var testArry:[String] = ["1", "a", "c"]
  var body: some View {
  List {
      ForEach(testArry) { obj in
          Text("test")
      }
    }
  }
  }

  #if DEBUG

  struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
     ContentView()
   }
  }
  #endif
  ```

> Error : Unable to infer closure type in the current context

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you could use `.identified(by: \.self)` like this :

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {

    var testArry:[String] = ["1", "a", "c"]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(testArry.identified(by: \.self)) { obj in
                Text("test")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57314994) is the correct answer. The `ForEach` method signature has changed with Xcode 11 Beta 5, and the `identified(by:)` method has been deprecated:

```swift
public struct ForEach<Data, ID, Content> where Data : RandomAccessCollection, ID : Hashable
```

The autocomplete shows it as:

```swift
ForEach(Data, id: KeyPath<Data.Element, ID>, content: (Data.Element) -> Content)
```

Therefore, when using Xcode 11 Beta 5, your code will be:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View 
{
  var testArry:[String] = ["1", "a", "c"]
  var body: some View 
  {
    List 
    {
        // The updated ForEach method, as of Xcode 11 Beta 5
        ForEach(testArry, id: \.self)
        { obj in
            Text("test")
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try conforming Identifiable protocol like this below:-

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var testArry: [TestArray] = [TestArray(value: "1"), TestArray(value: "a"), TestArray(value: "c")]
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(testArry) { obj in
                Text("\(obj.value)")
            }
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
class TestArray: Identifiable {
    let value: String
    init(value: String) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.identified(by: \.self)` on the array to have SwiftUI use the value itself as the identifier. So you should change your code with following.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var testArry:[String] = ["1", "a", "c"]
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(testArry.identified(by: \.self)) { obj in
                Text("test")
            }
        }
    }
}
```