# Using ForEach with a string array - [String] has no member 'identified'

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm using Xcode 11 beta 5 and what I had it doesn't work anymore. This is my code:

```
struct ModeView : View {
  @EnvironmentObject var state: IntentionState

  var body: some View {
      Picker(selection: $state.selection, label: Text("")) {
        ForEach(state.modes.identified(by: \.self)) { mode in
          Text(mode)
        }
      }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
  }
}
```

The error is in the line `ForEach(uistate.modes.identified(by: \.self)) { mode in` and it says:

> Value of type '[String]' has no member 'identified'

When I was using Xcode 11 beta 4 it worked perfectly. The question now is how to use ForEach with an array string in Xcode beta 5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ForEach` syntax changed a little bit in Beta 5.

Have you tried:

```
ForEach(state.modes, id: \.self) { mode in
    Text(mode)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the solution

Answer (score 1):

As per the apple release note, it's known issue from their end. We have to wait for another release.

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes/ios_ipados_13_beta_5_release_notes

[image]

Comment: What would it be a complex expression? In my case, what I have in the closure seems to be very simple

Comment: @fdelafuente What happens if you try extracting that expression to a separate variable, and pass the variable to `ForEach`?

Answer (score 1):

The `identified(by:)` method has been deprecated, the correct syntax is now:

`init(Data, id: KeyPath<Data.Element, ID>, content: (Data.Element) -> Content)`

or after moving the content into a closure :

```swift
ForEach(state.modes, id: \.self) { mode in Text(mode) }
```

Answer (score 0):

let suppose you have a name array like this:

```
let names = ["mike","Jack","jill"]

ForEach(names, id: \.self) { Text($0) }
```

`Text($0)` - this will print all elements from your names array.

Note:

> Use `backslashsign.self` instead `.self`, somehow backslash sign is not working here